# Google App Engine - How to remember user login?

Tags: google-app-engine

I haven't been able to figure out if it's possible to have a 'remember me' option available to users logging into GAE applications with the integrated Google accounts.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *remember me on this computer* checkbox on Google login page. And it works for me. Do you need something different?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response.  Looked a little harder and found the issue.  When visiting the login page, if you are recognized (ie. the username is already populated), the remember me checkbox isn't there.  If you click sign in with a different user the box appears and you can use that functionality.